# Spring config server with JDBC is throwing Invalid config server configuration error

Tags: spring-cloud-config, spring-config

I want to use JDBC mysql with Spring cloud config server, but always failed, this is what I am doing:

Spring cloud version: Finchley.SR2

1. In POM.xml

   ```
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                   <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
   ```
2. Inside the application.config:

```
    spring.profiles.active= jdbc
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/config_db
    spring.datasource.username=root
    spring.datasource.password=12345
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    spring.datasource.platform= mysql
    spring.cloud.config.server.jdbc.sql= SELECT `key`, `value` FROM `properties` WHERE `application`=? AND `profile`=? AND `label`=?;
    spring.cloud.config.server.jdbc.order=0
    spring.cloud.config.server.default-profile=production
    spring.cloud.config.server.default-label=latest
```

Finally, when I start server, I am getting below errors:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
Description:
Invalid config server configuration.
Action:
If you are using the git profile, you need to set a Git URI in your configuration.  If you are using a native profile and have spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true, you need to use a composite configuration.
```

I am not using git here, why the error is about git url?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when used MySQL.
It seems to be an issue with MySQL JdbcTemplate ([look here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1128)).

I switched to H2 to store configuration and it works.

I wonder if there any workaround to use MySQL?

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem with MySQL. I will take a look, if I have any luck I will share.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I attempt to remove the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class` on start up i.e.

> @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })

When I just used

> @SpringBootApplication

everything worked as expected.

My reason for excluding the class was to stop the auto generation of a password on startup.